# VB.net reading serial ports opened by third party

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

I've a program that opens a serial port and sends ascii to an Epson printer using ESC/POS commands.  Want I want to do if possible is to capture the output of this com port, reformat it and send it to various places.  I've heard of programs/seen programs capture the data from an opened com port that they didn't open.  Star for instance have a service that can read a port and then fire it to their USB or Ethernet printers.  Can I do this in vb.net? I know I can make an instance of com 2 and open then read incoming, but how would I capture data from a port that's been opened by another program?  Won't it throw an exception that the port is already in use.  Anyone done anything like this before?

Comment: It requires a device driver, a filter driver that you insert ahead of the port's normal driver.  SysInternals' PortMon utility is probably the best known example.  You of course cannot write those in vb.net, you'll have to go shopping.

Comment: If anyone comes across this in the future the com0com project helped me out.